# How to return the indexes of a pair from 2 separate lists?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am a beginner, trying to practice my skills in Python.

For the question that I am practising on, I have to return a list that shows the indexes of the following pairs: Girl and Boy Set A, Girl and Boy Set B, Girl and Boy Set C.

- If Girl = 3, then Girl is Girl A.
- If Girl = 6, then Girl is Girl B.
- If Girl = 12, then Girl is Girl C.
- If Boy = 1, then Boy is Boy A.
- If Boy = 4, then Boy is Boy B.
- If Boy = 8, then Boy is Boy C.

I have already identified the indexes of Girls and Boys but I am unsure how to pair them and print the indexes of the pairs.

Here are my codes:

```
arr_girls = [3, 6, 12, 3, 6, 12]
arr_boys = [1, 4, 8, 3, 4]

def girls_and_boys (arr_girls, arr_boys):
    for i in arr_girls:
        if i == 3:
            print("Index of Girl A: ", arr_girls.index(3))
        elif i == 6:
            print("Index of Girl B: ", arr_girls.index(6))
        elif i == 12:
            print("Index of Girl C: ", arr_girls.index(12))

    for i in arr_boys:
        if i == 1:
            print("Index of Boy A: ", arr_boys.index(1))
        elif i == 4:
            print("Index of Boy B: ", arr_boys.index(4))
        elif i == 8:
            print("Index of Boy C: ", arr_boys.index(8))

print(girls_and_boys(arr_girls, arr_boys))
```

Expected Output: To return a list that shows the indexes of the following pairs: Girl and Boy Set A, Girl and Boy Set B, Girl and Boy Set C.

```
0,0
1,1
2,2
4,4
```

Comment: Is that the full question? I am unable to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JacksonPro I have ammended the question

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match the code you have provided. How do you get 4? your output only gives 0, 1, 2

Comment: @JacksonPro as mentioned in the question, I am unsure how to proceed further with the current code in order to achieve the expected output.

Comment: @JacksonPro 4,4 is derived from the 5th elements of arr_girls and arr_boys respectively

Comment: @JacksonPro what do you mean by 12th index? there are only 6 elements in that array.

Comment: sorry I meant 12 as list element

Comment: why output skips 3,3 ?

Answer (score 0):

> For the question that I am practising on, I have to return a list that
> shows the indexes of the following pairs: Girl and Boy Set A, Girl and
> Boy Set B, Girl and Boy Set C.

I cannot really understand what are you trying to do but from the expected output the solution might be to determine the minimum length of the two arrays, then simply print.
If in the expected output `(3,3)` is skipped because you forgot to write it:

```
arr_girls = [3, 6, 12, 3, 6, 12]
arr_boys = [1, 4, 8, 3, 4]

def girls_and_boys(arr_girls, arr_boys):
    upper_limit = len(arr_girls)
    if len(arr_boys) < upper_limit:
        upper_limit = len(arr_boys)
    for i in range(upper_limit):
        print(i, i)

girls_and_boys(arr_girls, arr_boys)
```

If in the expected output `(3,3)` is skipped because `arr_girls[3]=3` and `arr_boys[3]=3` the solution changes to:

```
def girls_and_boys(arr_girls, arr_boys):
    upper_limit = len(arr_girls)
    if len(arr_boys) < upper_limit:
        upper_limit = len(arr_boys)
    for i in range(upper_limit):
        boy = arr_boys[i]
        girl = arr_girls[i]
        if boy != girl:
            print(i, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get desired output:

```
arr_girls = [3, 6, 12, 3, 6, 12]
arr_boys = [1, 4, 8, 3, 4]

def girls_and_boys(arr_girls, arr_boys):
    for idx, val in enumerate(zip(arr_girls, arr_boys)):
        if val[0] == 3 and val[1] == 1:
            print(f"{idx}, {idx}")
        elif val[0] == 6 and val[1] == 4:
            print(f"{idx}, {idx}")
        elif val[0] == 12 and val[1] == 8:
            print(f"{idx}, {idx}")

girls_and_boys(arr_girls, arr_boys)
```

Output will be:

```
0, 0
1, 1
2, 2
4, 4
```